# Why my play again button isnt working SpriteKit

Tags: swift, xcode, button, sprite-kit, skspritenode

i have problem with my play again button. I created it from image in inside touchBegan func i made it change scenes but it aint working

```
    class GameScene: SKScene {
 
    var playagain = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "unnamed")  
  
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        playagain.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.minY + 40)
        playagain.size = CGSize(width: 250, height: 120)
        self.addChild(playagain)
}
       override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
        for touch in touches {
            let location = touch.location(in: self)
            let node : SKNode = self.atPoint(location)
            if (node.name == "unnamed"){
                let gamescene = GameScene(fileNamed: "GameScene")
                gamescene!.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.resizeFill
                self.view?.presentScene(gamescene!, transition: SKTransition.fade(with: UIColor.black, duration: 1.5))
 }}}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to access GameScene from GameScene?  It doesn't make sense.  Why is 'play again button'?  Where does it come from?

Comment: @ElTomato There is no other scene for game. At the scene where is game, in lower part is score and i would love to add some reset/reload/play again button which resets scene/score/everyhing so you can start to play all over. Its a game where you match balls and if there isnt other balls to match, now you need to RR all game. (P.S i am learning so this is small usless game)

Comment: Hint: Go back to the point where the game started initially

Comment: @ElTomato What do you mean by that?

Comment: Hint 2: `SKScene` is not a view controller

Comment: @ElTomato Yes i know it, but does that mean that for GameScene i cant call view reset?

Comment: Hint 3: Instruct your view controller what to do

Answer (score 1):

add this before you add the playagain button.

playagain.name = “unnamed”